# Android: how to create a "shop" limited version of Android

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-version

I try to explain better:
I want to put some tablets in my shop for my customers. I want them to use only a few apps that I've created.

So I need an Android version (or a launcher version, maybe?) where you can only choose between some apps to be played. All the settings, all the other apps and everything else must be unreachable (or, better, only reachable if you know the password).

Anyone has any suggestion on how to do it or where do I start?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One Google search led me to the following:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en

Just whichever one you want and and hide the apps you don't want. It will hide them in the drawer as well. Nova Launcher already looks like stock Android, or close enough if you want that. In fact they both do.